# Merging a List of objects containing lists

Tags: java, java-8

I have a List of custom Foo objects each containing 2 lists of Cat and Dog objects as seen below:

```
class Foo {
   List<Cat> cats;
   List<Dog> dogs;
}

class Cat {
   int id;
}

class Dog {
   String name;
}
```

I have a method where I pass in a List request and I would like to flatten that to a single Foo object containing each requests dogs and cats flattened together. Is there a clean compact way to do so?

Source List:

```
List<Cat> catsForOne = new ArrayList<>(); // add a bunch of cats
List<Cat> catsForTwo = new ArrayList<>(); // add a bunch of cats
List<Dog> dogsForTwo = new ArrayList<>(); // add a bunch of dogs

List<Foo> requests = new ArrayList<>();
Foo one = Foo.builder().cats(catsForOne).build();
Foo two = Foo.builder().dogs(dogsForTwo).cats(catsForTwo).build();

requests.add(one);
requests.add(two);
```

Result should be:

Foo with a List = catsForOne + catsForTwo and a List = dogsForTwo

This is a toy example but you can imagine that foo has about 5-6 collections (ie. Cat, Dog, Pig, Duck etc.) and I would like to have a compact solution with Java 8. The naive one that I can do is to loop over the requests and keep adding all the collections one by one to a final result Foo.

Assume Foo, Cat, Dog etc. are from an external library and thus their source code cannot be altered.

Comment: Can you provide definition of your source list with request?

Comment: `List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>(); for (Foo foo : fooList) { list.addAll(foo.cats); list.addAll(foo.dogs); }` Lists flattened. If that's not what you meant, then clarify the question.

Comment: edited the question, hope its more clear!

Comment: So you want to *merge* multiple `Foo` objects?

Comment: @Andreas yes sorry for the wording

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do,

```
Foo foo = requests.stream().reduce(new Foo(), (f1, f2) -> {
            f1.cats.addAll(f2.cats);
            f1.dogs.addAll(f2.dogs);
            return f1;
        });
```

As with lambda, it is very easy to introduce bugs. Just keep it simple and write a few extra lines.

Answer (score 5):

You could just collect them separately and then create a new `Foo` object and assign your `lists` to it.

```
 List<Dog> collectDogs = foos.stream().flatMap(foo -> foo.getCats().stream())
                       .collect(Collectors.toList());
 List<Cat> collectCats = foos.stream().flatMap(foo -> foo.getDogs().stream())
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

and then

```
Foo result = new Foo();
result.setDogs(collectDogs);
result.setCats(collectCats);
```

Answer (score 1):

To merge multiple `Foo` objects, using Java 8 streams, implement a merge method:

```
class Foo {
    List<Cat> cats;
    List<Dog> dogs;

    Foo merge(Foo other) {
        this.cats.addAll(other.cats);
        this.dogs.addAll(other.dogs);
        return this;
    }
}
```

You can now easily merge all `Foo` objects in a `List` into a single `Foo` object, using the [`reduce()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-T-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) stream method.

```
List<Foo> requests = ...;
Foo merged = requests.stream().reduce(new Foo(), Foo::merge);
```

---

**UPDATE**

The above code is not safe for parallel use, since the `merge()` method updates the current object. For parallel use, the `Foo` object should be treated as immutable.

Also, question was enhanced to say that class `Foo` is from external library, and cannot be changed, so the `merge()` method needs to be separate.

So, do it like this:

```
class Test {
    public static void test() {
        List<Foo> requests = ...;
        Foo merged = requests.stream().reduce(new Foo(), Test::mergeFoos);
    }

    public static Foo mergeFoos(Foo a, Foo b) {
        Foo merged = new Foo();
        merged.cats = mergeLists(a.cats, b.cats);
        merged.dogs = mergeLists(a.dogs, b.dogs);
        merged.pigs = mergeLists(a.pigs, b.pigs);
        merged.ducks = mergeLists(a.ducks, b.ducks);
        return merged;
    }
    private static <E> List<E> mergeLists(List<E> a, List<E> b) {
        List<E> merged = new ArrayList<>(a.size() + b.size());
        merged.addAll(a);
        merged.addAll(b);
        return merged;
    }
}
```

If you don't want a `Foo` created when the list is empty, you do it like this:

```
Optional<Foo> merged = requests.stream().reduce(Test::merge);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to Foo that will allow you to add the lists together, then loop through your Foos adding them to you one true "flattened" Foo.

```
class Foo
{
  ...
  flatten(Foo a)
  {
    cats.addAll(a.cats);
    dogs.addAll(a.dogs);
  }
}

...

Foo result = new Foo();
for(Foo a: fooList)
{
  result.flatten(a);
}
```

Comment: Right, this is similar to what i have currently but wanted to know if there was some neater way to express it using the Stream API or some other Java8 feature.

Comment: @JohnBaum Yes, using `reduce()` as shown in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46373985/5221149). Method name not important. It can be named `flatten` like in this answer.